# Is element.empty() equivalent to element.innerHTML = ""?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

Like the title says. If it's not then what would be the same as .innerHTML =  "" ?

Comment: To [the documentation!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element).

Comment: Is it the same? Not exactly, `innerHTML` is a property of an `HTMLElement` whereas `empty()` is a method on the `jQuery` instance. There is no `HTMLElement.empty()`

Answer (score 1):

It's nearly the same. If you look at [the source](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js) for the method, you'll see that it's:

```
empty: function() {
    var elem,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; ( elem = this[ i ] ) != null; i++ ) {
        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {

            // Prevent memory leaks
            jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );

            // Remove any remaining nodes
            elem.textContent = "";
        }
    }

    return this;
},
```

And assigning the empty string to the `.textContent` of an element is the same as assigning the empty string to the `.innerHTML` of an element.

The only difference is that `.empty` calls `.cleanData`, which removes a number of jQuery-specific data/events associated with the element, if there happen to be any.

Comment: This `if ( elem.nodeType === 1 )` is actually quite surprising, since the (main) difference between `.textContent` and `.innerHTML` is that the former is accessible on all Nodes, while the latter is only on Elements. But indeed `$(new Text("foo")).empty().text()` still returns `"foo"`... weird choice I'd say, though I guess there isn't many folks playing with Nodes and jQuery together.

Comment: Ps: the "sub" difference is that, per-specs, `textContent` calls directly *replace all* with nothing, while `.innerHTML` does go through the HTML parser, which invokes a new Document node etc. But I'd expect browsers to take a shortcut with the empty string.